# AWS SNS - Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSSNSErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns, aws-mobilehub, amazon-mobile-hub

I am using `AWS` for one of my projects and I am trying to make it so that users are able to create `SNS` - topics and subscribe to `SNS` - topics. When doing a request I get `Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSSNSErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"`.

It seems like there are some missing permissions in my project and can't figure out what and where. Also I think this might be related with the fact that the `AWS Cognito` is in region `Ireland (EUWest1)` and the `AWSSNS` and others are in region `Frankfurt(EUCentral1)`.

Is there a way I can change the `AWS SNS` to the other region, or add permissions in such a way this would work.

Also... I am able to send push notifications to devices from the console.

Here is also the code I use to request a topic creation. Which works on a demo project

```
func createTopic(topicName: String) {
    let topic = AWSSNSCreateTopicInput()
    topic?.name = topicName

    AWSSNS.default().createTopic(topic!, completionHandler: { topicResponse, error in

        if error != nil {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }

        if let topicResponse = topicResponse, let myEndpoint = self.myEndpoint {
            self.subscribeToTopic(topicArn: topicResponse.topicArn!)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi! Did you find the solution? I have the same problem

Comment: Hi Alexander, sorry for the late reply. At the moment I did not find a solution. I was forced to postpone the issue for the moment due to time. Will keep you updated since soon will try to find a fix again